# DOMElement to array

Tags: php, domdocument

need to convert DOMElement to array.

have a node:

```
var_dump($node);
object(DOMElement)#68 (0) {}
```

witch looks like:

```
var_dump($node->C14N());
string(93) "<places><wagon class="1" type="С">166</wagon><wagon class="2" type="С">409</wagon></places>"
```

but was confused by this:

```
var_dump(count($node->childNodes));
int(1)
```

and the question: how to get real count of nodes?

Comment: try echo"<pre>";print_r($node); And show us the results.

Comment: DOMElement Object
(
) ..... like as var_dump i wrote in question code

Comment: @Subdigger maybe post EDIT1 as a new question? as its not relevant to your original question. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DOMNode::$childNodes is a DOMNodeList object. It is not Countable. It will always return one (even if empty). Use its length property instead:

```
$count = $node->childNodes->length;
```